# Form Reactive with custom input

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I want to create a form using a custom input component, and am having the following problem.

> Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'nome' Stack
>   trace:
>   _throwError@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js:2510:11
>   setUpControl@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js:2380:9
>   FormGroupDirective.prototype.addControl@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js:6736:9
>   FormControlName.prototype._setUpControl@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js:7386:45
>   FormControlName.prototype.ngOnChanges@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js:7299:13

This is my input component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pf-input-text',
  templateUrl: './pf-input-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pf-input-text.component.scss']
})
export class PfInputTextComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() formControlName: any;

  //falta trim

  @Input() maxlength: string;
  @Input() minlength: string;

  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Input() required: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  }

}
```

html:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input 
      type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

I am trying to use it as follows:

```
<form [formGroup]="empresaForm">
  <div class="form-row">

    <app-pf-input-text formControlName="nome"></app-pf-input-text>

  </div>
</form>
```

This is my form:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { Empresa } from '../empresa.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-empresa-cadastro',
  templateUrl: './empresa-cadastro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empresa-cadastro.component.css']
})
export class EmpresaCadastroComponent implements OnInit {

  empresaForm: FormGroup;

  nomeControl: FormControl;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  createForm() {
    this.nomeControl = new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(10)
    ]);
  }

  createFormControl() {
    console.log('Criando FormControl');
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const empresa = this.empresaForm.value as Empresa;
    console.log('Empresa: ', empresa);
  }

  limpar() {
    this.empresaForm.reset();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

}
```

I'm not sure how to pass the formControlName directive to the input, through my custom input.

Comment: `formControlName` is reserved input https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b3a10e0a42cca072ab5bc9245f7e312d5cee3e5d/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L158. Try `controlName` or implement ControlValueAccessor

Comment: As @yurzui mentions - I had the exact same issue with `formControl` - renaming to `providedFormControl` fixed it

Comment: I switched to '<app-pf-input-text controlName="nome"></app-pf-input-text>'. It worked, you no longer have the error displayed. but I can not get the validations anymore.

Comment: *ngIf="nomeControl.errors && (nomeControl.dirty || nomeControl.touched)" It does not work anymore.